# Find the interval of convergence $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(x-1)^{2n}}{3^{2n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(x-1)^{2n}}{3^{2n-1}}$$

So i started using the ratio test
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left|\frac{(n+1)(x-1)^{2(n+1)}}{3^{2(n+1)-1}}.\frac{3^{2n-1}}{n(x-1)^{2n}}\right|$$

simplifying...

$$L=\left|\frac{(x-1)^2}{3^2}\right|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}\\=\left|\frac{(x-1)^2}{3^2}\right|.1$$

so $\left|\frac{(x-1)^2}{3^2}\right|<1$ to converge

$$(x-1)^2<3^2\\
(x-1)<3\\
-2<x<4$$

And now i have to test those limits, but in my book the answer is {-2,4}, anyone can spot where is my mistake ?

---

edit i don't know why i changed from $(x-1)^2 \to (x-2)^2$ in line 3 but this was my mistake

Comment: You suddenly wrote $x-2$ instead of $x-1$. In the original question you had $x-1$.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw seconds ago haha I'm kind sleepy rn

Comment: Hint : start defining $t=\left(\frac {x-1}3\right)^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At $x=2$, the series converges by the ratio test. At $x=4$. the limit of the $n-$th term as $n \to \infty$ is not 0, so the series diverges. The interval of convergence is [2,4).